# Can't declare a variable in an if statement

Tags: c#

I can't figure out why this won't work.

The "bits" variable don't change the value in the if statements and for me it's looks like it should work.

```
static string IPMask(string CIDR)
{
    int intCIDR;
    Int32.TryParse(CIDR, out intCIDR);
    int bits = 32 - intCIDR;
    string strmask = "11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111";

    int dot;
    if (bits < 8)
    {
        dot = 0;
    }
    else if (bits > 8)
    {
        dot = 1;
    }
    else if (bits > 16)
    {
        dot = 2;
    }
    else if (bits > 24)
    {
        dot = 3;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{dot}");
    string Mask = strmask.Remove(strmask.LastIndexOf("") - bits + dot);

    return Mask;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what is the error, and on what line?

Comment: You don't declare a variable in the if statement anywhere. You only assign them.

Comment: There are execution paths where `dot` isn't assigned a value. C# doesn't allow that (and local variables don't have a default initialization. You can either initialize the value e.g. `int dot = 0` or provide and `else` statement that assigns the value you need for all other cases.

Comment: The error code is "Use of unassigned local variable 'dot'"
It starts the error in the "Console.WriteLine($"{dot}");", but if i remove it, the error comes in the "string Mask = strmask.Remove(strmask.LastIndexOf("") - bits + dot);"

Comment: Instead of all the if-else you could do `dot = bits / 8;` taking advantage of integer devision discarding the rest

Comment: Since your if/else if statements do not have a trailing else the compiler does not know if `dot` is ever assigned to and in fact if the value was 8 exactly you don't set it as you check < 8 then > 8.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the program and seeing why you were getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I put in `24`. The code will come first to the check where `bits > 8`. `24` is greater than `8`, and so that code will run. The later conditions are `else if` checks, meaning they won't even be attempted, because the prior condition already matched.

Second, let's say I put in `8` exactly. That doesn't match **any** of the conditions, meaning the `dots` variable would never be assigned.

You want something like this:

```
static string IPMask(string CIDR)
{
    int intCIDR;
    Int32.TryParse(CIDR, out intCIDR);
    int bits = 32 - intCIDR;
    string strmask = "11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111";

    int dot = 0;
    if (bits > 24)
    {
        dot = 3;
    }
    else if (bits > 16)
    {
        dot = 2;
    }
    else if (bits > 8)
    {
        dot = 1;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(dot);
    return strmask.Remove(strmask.Length - bits + dot);
}
```

... though that last line still needs some work.

Comment: Sure, but that's not the first issue. The variable isn't guaranteed to have a value after the if's, so compiler error.

Comment: Oh i see what you mean there, but how should i make it then? So it could work.
I can't just remove "else" right?

Comment: @Sjippi Initialize `dot`  (like he posted) and/or have an `else` statement at the end